# Where to get kubectl man pages?

Tags: manpage, kubernetes, doc

Any suggestion where I can get and install kubectl man pages? Asking Google all the time is getting annoying.

I want to be able to see the man page from the command line like:

```
$ man kubectl pods
```

I obviously know about the documentation online on the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kubectl` CLI is written in Golang, and use [Cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) features to automatic generate documentation based on subcommands, flags, etc.

So, you can use `kubectl --help` to see all the available options. Furthermore, you can dig into specific subcommands options (e.g., `kubectl describe --help`, `kubectl get --help` and so on).

More than that, you can use `kubectl explain` to describe the fields associated with each supported API resources, which is very useful when writing templates. Examples:

```
  # Get the documentation of the resource and its fields
  kubectl explain pods

  # Get the documentation of a specific field of a resource
  kubectl explain pods.spec.containers
```

Comment: That's still not a system man page, and doesn't integrate with the rest of the system. It's an annoying gap.

Comment: @tchrist I agree. Thats the reason why kubectl is missing in my favorite tool explainshell.com

Comment: There is no way to get global flags this way. `kubectl help` just lists commands and not global flags.

Comment: From output: "Use `kubectl options` for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands)."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a man page for this. But the CLI reference is here and can be bookmarked:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/

Comment: yah, this is exactly what I don't need :-D

Comment: @andrew.46 it wasn't. The "yah" in my previous post was mentioned sarcastically since I was asking for the man pages, not for the doc on the internet which I obviously know about.